# Android Studio Zxing Integration

Tags: android, android-studio, zxing

I am trying to build an app which uses input from a scanned barcode and parses it so it can be used as input to a database.
I have been trying to work with the Zxing barcode scanner, but I am really struggling to integrate it into my app. 
I have followed a number of tutorials, none of which have given me any success.
The closest I have got to achieving the required functionality was by following this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162
However, this requires that Barcode Scanner app be installed on the device, and I would rather my app has it's own scanning capabilities.
Would someone please be able to point me towards an idiot-proof tutorial for Android Studio?

Comment: which version you use of device...??

Answer (score 0):

For integrating the Zxing library into your application add the following dependency into your `build.gradle` file of your android project.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.7.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**My project is developed on Eclipse.**

At first, download the [ZXing lib](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/Zxing%20Lib%20Android)

and then add this lib into your app as library...
[ Right click on your project->Properties... ]

Then write this code:

```
btnScan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try{
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE,PRODUCT_MODE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

And :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == 0) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                textViewFormat.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
                textViewData.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));

                Uri imageURI = intent.getData();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try{
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageURI);
                    scannedBitmap.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT") + ":" + intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"), 5000).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                textViewFormat.setText("");
                textViewData.setText("Cancelled By user");
            }

        }
```

For full project download my git [repo](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/BarCodeQR)

Manifesto:
You have to give permission into your android manifesto file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".encode.EncodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- This allows us to handle the Share button in Contacts. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- This allows us to handle sharing any plain text . -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```